# Why can't I access any of the previous/current databases I made in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio-2013

I'm having a serious problem with my MVC projects. I'm using Entity Framework to build my databases.
However recently, ever time I build a database using Entity Framework I cannot connect to my databases.
It says when I tried to connect in my Server Explorer  "Cannot open database "CampDb" requested by login. The login failed for  user ACER\Apu".

I've been looking online and trying to fix it, but to no success.
Does Anyone know what could be blocking me from Accessing my databases?
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Check it with the same credentials with SQL Server or Express Client, see if they are working or not.

Comment: How do I get them? I never user SQL Server Credentials before. Sorry for my inexperience.

Comment: hmm checkout the web.config or app.config for the connection string.

Comment: Your windows account does not have permissions on your db in SQL. You probably have `Integrated Security=True` in your connection string. Either grant your account permissions on the db or change the connection string to a user/password combination that does have permission.

Comment: Ok, I managed to get past it by saying integrated security = "false" . As of now I'm building the site so this will do as a temporary work around. Thank you both for your help.